# C++ - std::fstream read() does not read full file

Tags: c++, fstream

I would like to create a MIDI interpreter to use in a bigger project, but I'm currently facing a huge problem : It seems that in some cases, my file is not completely read, and so I don't have the whole data I need... For example, I have a file that is around 30 000 bytes long, and the fstream::read() function reads only around 3000 of them...

My code is below, if someone may have an idea...

I haven't found any similar question, but if there are any, please tell me.

```
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("Songs/" + filename + ".mid");
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned char> fileData;

    while (file.read((char *)&c, 1))
    {
        fileData.push_back(c);
    }
    file.close();
```

Comment: Try opening the file in binary mode `file.open("Songs/" + filename + ".mid", ios::binary)`

Comment: How is the program failing?  Is the `while` loop exiting early? Or does the whole thing crash?

Comment: @NathanOliver It worked ! Thanks !

Comment: @Spencer It seems the while loop exits early, as the program is crashing later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, file streams use "in + out" mode to open a filestream for a text file. Try to combine exactly "in" (as you read from the file) and "binary" (as your file is not a plain text), something like this:

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open("Songs/" + filename + ".mid", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
if (!file.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
    return;
}
std::vector<unsigned char> fileData;

while (file.read((char *)&c, 1))
{
    fileData.push_back(c);
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Using std::fstream::binary option worked, thank you !

Comment: @BenoitTachet, to play safe it's better to fully designate your intent - do not underestimate other bits at this bitmask.

Comment: You don't need to specify `std::ios_base::in` explicitly when using `std::ifstream`, it always enables that for you. `std::ifstream` never uses `std::ios_base::out`, but `std::fstream` and `std::ofstream` do. `std::ifstream` is like an input-only `std::fstream`, and `std::ofstream` is like an output-only `std::fstream`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for these informations, it may come in handy